# Display part of fortune in different color

Tags: command-line, bashrc, fortune

I created a custom fortune file for my favourite tweets in the format tweet and then the @username in a new line. An Example is:

> "You've changed."
>   "Yeah I know, I'm a Transformer."
>
> @LetsQuoteComedy

I want to display the tweet in a different color, say white, and the @username in another color, like black. How can I do this in the terminal?

Also, I would like to put that in my `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Read [Bash Colours](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html). (You might also want to get acquainted with [Pygments](http://pygments.org/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: [coloring command output](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2012/06/coloring-output-of-cat.html)

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
OIFS=$IFS #save old IFS

frtn=$(fortune tweets) #load up a fortune
IFS='@' #new IFS
arr=($frtn) #split fortune into array along IFS

tweet=$(tput setaf 3)"${arr[0]}"$(tput setaf default) #tweet - dark yellow color
uname=$(tput setaf 7)"@${arr[1]}\n"$(tput setaf default) #create @username - white
echo -e "$tweet$uname"; #to retain newlines in original fortune, echo between quotes

IFS=$OIFS #restore old IFS
```

Just copy paste that into your `.bashrc` file.

**EDIT**

The result:
[image]