# bash_profile colors

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I have found these settings in many bash profile files and I don't know what they mean or do. Can anybody explain them? Thanks!

```
# Terminal colors
NM="\[\033[0;38m\]" #means no background and white lines
HI="\[\033[0;37m\]" #change this for letter colors
HII="\[\033[0;31m\]" #change this for letter colors
SI="\[\033[0;33m\]" #this is for the current directory
IN="\[\033[0m\]"
```

Comment: Practical example: [Display part of fortune in different color](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328029/display-part-of-fortune-in-different-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are syntaxes for colouring your gnome-terminal.

For example, the first one,

```
NM="\[\033[0;38m\]" #means no background and white lines
```

Here,

- `NM` is a variable
- `\[\033[` and `m\]` is the escape sequence for indicating the text in between is a colour code
- `0;38` indicates no background and white lines(as mentioned in the comments)

---

**Reference:**

- [Colours in bash](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)