# Create a custom syntax highlight in gedit

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting

Following [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328029/display-part-of-fortune-in-different-color) from long ago, I am still trying to tweak my fortune handling capabilities. The display in terminal is awesome, just one thing remains - syntax highlighting in Gedit as I add, edit or delete individual fortunes.

My custom fortune files are in this format:

```
Friend: "Whats a good movie?"
Me: "Snakes on a plane"
Friend: "Whats it about?"
Me: "Horses... horses on a boat..."
@AYYSIAN
%
Me on my wedding: you still like me, right?
@ComedyPosts
%
Mum: Son I'd love to meet your girlfriend...
Me: Me too...
@ComedyTruth
%
Doctor: "Ok, so what's wrong, how are you feeling?"
Me: *Looks at mum waiting for her to explain*
@ChildhoodFact
%
Friend: 75% of people are good at maths...
Me: Mmmmh, I guess then am in the remaining 18%...
@TheFunnyTeens
%
I loved the Titanic. My favorite character was the iceberg
@__GrumpyCat
```

It's basically `a tweet`, `@name` and the `%` character. Then repeat.

When I open it in Gedit, everything is black.
I'm looking for a way to create a syntax highlighting file that will convert the `%` to something like blue and the `@name` to something like magenta. The tweet can remain black.

**NOTE:**

1. The fortune files are mime-type `text/plain` and only the given format really distinguishes them from another plain text file.
2. Fortune files have no extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create and open your fortune language file:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/fortune.lang
sudo -i gedit /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/fortune.lang
```

Paste the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language id="fortune" _name="Fortune" version="2.0" _section="Markup">
  <metadata>
    <property name="mimetypes">text/plain</property>
    <property name="globs">*.</property>
  </metadata>

  <styles>
    <style id="at"      _name="@ sign"  map-to="def:constant" />
    <style id="percent" _name="percent sign"  map-to="def:comment" />
  </styles>
  <definitions>
    <context id="fortune">
      <include>
        <context id="at" style-ref="at">
          <start>@</start>
          <end>$</end>
        </context>
        <context id="percent" style-ref="percent">
          <start>%</start>
          <end>$</end>
        </context>
      </include>
    </context>
  </definitions>
</language>
```

Make sure it is accessible:

```xml
sudo chmod 0644 /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/screenplay.lang
```

Restart gedit.

[Reference - my source answer](https://superuser.com/questions/353391/custom-gedit-syntax-highlighting-for-dummies)

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Thanks alot, will try this out. One thing though, fortune files have no extension, the reason for the `text/plain` mime type. Does that mean `<property name="globs">*.fort</property>` becomes `<property name="globs">*</property>`?

Comment: @Parto That would apply it to all files with no extension, but as most are .txt that would be fine. Change it to `<property name="globs">*.</property>`, and I've updated the answer with this!

Comment: Massive thanks. I just used this to add [Twig syntax highlighting](https://github.com/gabrielcorpse/gedit-twig-template-language/blob/master/twig.lang) to gedit.

Comment: @TRiG Glad to have helped!